# system service is not started on fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, rhel, amazon-ami

Using the below code, I created a service

Code snippet from agentInstaller.sh

```
fileAgentController="agent_controller.sh"
if [[ "$os" = "debian" ]] ;then
            update-rc.d $fileAgentController defaults
     else
            chkconfig --add /etc/init.d/$fileAgentController
     fi


  export start="start"
  export command="/etc/init.d/$fileAgentController"
  sh $command ${start}
```

Above code successfully start the service 'agent_controller.sh' on **Amazon Linux AMI 2017.03 - amzn rhel fedora and Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS**
But give error with following machine details :-

1. ID="rhel"
2. ID_LIKE="fedora"
3. VERSION_ID="7.3"
4. PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.3 (Maipo)"
5. CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.3:GA:server"
6. Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)

I encountered following error on above machine :-

1. Reloading systemd:                                         [  OK  ]
2. Starting agent_controller.sh (via systemctl):  Failed to start
   agent_controller.sh.service: Unit not found.
                                                              [FAILED]

Comment: if anyone available on this site, please help me.

Comment: Did you checked the service is exist in /etc/rc.d/init.d? Did you tried to run the service creation in shell, instead with the script? According to the info you provide the service is not exist so the install script may failed to create it. Rhel 7+ also using systemd and you created the service as it using initd still. Fortunetly rhel still compatible backwards so it less likely the issue, but would be better to use the actual initialization then relay on its support to the legacy one.

Comment: @Edvin, Thanks for the help. File is missing. Now it works.